# C plotting library GR not working

Tags: c

I am trying to install C library GR [[Link]](https://gr-framework.org/c.html#) on Ubuntu 18.04, after following the instructions to install, there is no error while installing but when using it gives the error :

foo.c:2:10: fatal error: gr.h: No such file or directory
 #include 
          ^~~~~~
compilation terminated.

This is while compiling the example given on their installation page.

Is the installation faulty? Can anyone help me regarding this?

Thank You in advance.

Comment: Please improve the question: are you trying to compile the sample from the installation page or it's your project?

Comment: I am trying to compile the sample from installation page.

Comment: Did you install the dependencies?

Comment: Yes, I did install the dependencies.

Comment: The C compiler does not find the "gr.h" header file. 1) Check if the file exists and if you can access it. 2) Try to modify the example in: #include "path_to_gr.h/gr.h"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By specifying location of GR through addition flags the compilation is possible.
Assuming GR is installed in /usr/local/gr.
The command to run foo.c should be :

```
gcc -I/usr/local/gr/include foo.c -L/usr/local/gr/lib -lGR -Wl,-rpath,/usr/local/gr/lib
```